# (Angular 2+) ng-content projection without rendering the selector container

Tags: angular, projection

Can `<ng-content>` be used in the following way?

Defining:

```
<th>title</th>
<ng-content select="[stuff]"></ng-content>
```

Using:

```
<div stuff>
    <th>category</th>
</div>
```

The HTML that gets generated doesn't include the `<div stuff>`:

```
<th>title</th>
<th>category</th>
```

Comment: Angular doesn't provide any support for that.

Comment: Thank you! I have been googling it for a couple hours and trying to figure out, I won't waste anymore time then.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using ng-container

Replacing the `<div stuff>` with `<ng-container stuff>` should work

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhimgu